# Subcadena de n caracteres php

Tags: php, string

Buenas tardes  tengo una duda tengo este código

```
    $cadena= 'ABCDE';
    $n = '10';
    $arr=str_split($cadena);


    
     for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
     foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

     echo $imprimir=$value;
     }

     }
```

n es el numero de caracteres que debe llevar mi nueva cadena si colocara n=2 debería imprimirme AB solamente y si colocara n=6 debería imprimir ABCDEA eso es lo que debería realizar el código y es lo que esta fallando
ya que da como resultado ABCDE repetido 50 (50 caracteres)

Answer (score 2):

Estas haciendo diferentes loops, debes utilizar las posiciones del array, haciendo uso del operador residual `%`.

```
// Obtienes la longitud de la cadena
$q = count($arr);
for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) {
    // Obtienes la posición con el residual de $i sobre la longitud
    $pos = $i % $q;
    echo $arr[$pos];
}
```

Te explico como funciona el operador, cuando divides residualmente obtienes el residuo de una división:

```
0%5 es 0
1%5 es 1
5%5 es 0
6%5 es 1
```

Por lo tanto, reinicias las posiciones del array.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo jugando con funciones de cadena propias de PHP.

[str_repeat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-repeat.php): Multiplica la cadena $n veces

[strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php): mide la longitud de una cadena

[subsrt](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php): Extrae parte de una cadena

```
    $cadena= 'ABCDE';
    $n = 6;
    // Si la cadena no suficientemente larga la multiplicamos por si misma según $n
    $nuevacadena = str_repeat($cadena, (1+$n)/strlen($cadena));
    // Aplicamos la funcion de seleccionar una parte de la nueva cadena
    echo substr($nuevacadena, 0, $n);
```

Comment: Este ejemplo pretende ser simplemente una alternativa, en vez de trabajar con arrays, trabajar propiamente con cadenas.